# The output of double.ToString("P") changed after upgrading to Windows 10 1709

Tags: c#, windows, string-formatting

I noticed that the output of double.ToString("P") has changed after I updated to Windows 10 version 1709. 
Before the update I got as a result e.g. "100.00 %", but now it is "100.00%".
According to the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) it should be "100.00 %" as it was before.

Has anyone found the reason for this issue or a good solution to solve it? 
**Note:** As the culture and the format is set by users and this is already in production, I can't use a different culture or format.

Here a sample how I use the double.ToString function:

```
double val = 1;
string output = null;

output = val.ToString("P", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en"));
Console.WriteLine("Output:" + output);
```

Comment: I am still getting 100.00 % on windows 10

Comment: @GaurangDave What version of Windows 10? I'm on 1709 and I get it without the space, like the OP does.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#PFormatString It's culture-specific. That update probably brought with it a culture update.

Comment: I am on 1607 (windows 10)

Comment: @GaurangDave Well that's why - OP says it happened after he upgraded to 1709

Comment: I am on Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1709 Build 16299.309

Comment: Seems this is culture specific... so maybe check your culture settings, or force culture invariance from code?

Comment: I assume that FPU is different in different PC / OS version which is responsible for all floating point operations.

Comment: I tried it on different machines with the same culture "en". On older versions I get the "100 %", on my pc I get the wrong result

Comment: locally I get `en` : "100.00 %" - `en-GB` : "100.00%" - `en-US` : "100.00 %" - no culture :  "100.00%" - invariant culture : "100.00 %"

Comment: "en" is just a language, not a culture...

Comment: Does setting the culture like `ToString("P", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR")` as suggested by the link shared by @CodeCaster help?

Comment: no it didn't - I tried it with en-US and still get 100%

Comment: Try `ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: This is not the first time that a Win10 has caused a problem like this.  .NET pays attention to localization overrides and Win10 has added some but doesn't expose them in the Control Panel applet.  The MSDN article does explicitly warn about it in the "The placement of the percent sign" section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting  Run regedit.exe and check the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International key, it might be in there.

Comment: And, if you want it 100.00 % predictable... format it yourself without using the "P" shortcut.

Comment: The problem is that the customer has already the P shortcut in use. Otherwise I would already fixed it. I added a codefix by checking if the issue is present and then replace the shortcut with a working format string

Comment: btw. the issue is also present on the Windows 10 2018 Spring Update - version 1803 rs4